# Update the status in Linkedin

Tags: java, android, integration, linkedin-api

I need to do update the status in LinkedIn via Android Application. Can anyone please help regarding this. Is there any sample source code available for this.

I tried developing the code for posting update status in LinkedIn from the link https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2133 , But i'm facing the error as

```
10-11 15:19:16.406: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 15:19:16.406: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4641): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthConsumer
10-11 15:19:16.406: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4641):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthConsumer(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:246)
10-11 15:19:16.406: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4641):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:145)
10-11 15:19:16.406: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4641):     at com.snt.mylinkedin.LinkedinClient.onCreate(LinkedinClient.java:53)
```

Please anyone help to resolve this error.

Thanks & Regards
Krishnakumar p

Comment: Have you imported SignPost library inside your application?

Comment: Yes I had imported signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar with my application. But still I cant able to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can go up with scribe.....